# 3D PieChart using Core Plot in swift

Tags: swift, core-plot, pie-chart

I am trying to design a 3D PieChart using core plot.
So that I have the following code

```
    @IBOutlet weak var pieChartDataLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!
var pieItem:Int = 0
var pieChartValueArrayToShow = [AnyObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRectZero)
    graph.title = "PieChart"
    graph.paddingLeft = 0
    graph.paddingTop = 0
    graph.paddingRight = 0
    graph.paddingBottom = 0
    graph.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor

    let overlayGradient = CPTGradient()
    overlayGradient.gradientType = CPTGradientType.Radial
    overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0), atPosition: 0.9)
    overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4), atPosition: 1.0)

    let pie = CPTPieChart()
    //pie.borderLineStyle = linestyle
    pie.dataSource = self
    pie.delegate = self
    pie.pieRadius = (self.view.frame.size.width * 0.7)/2
    pie.overlayFill = CPTFill(gradient: overlayGradient)
    graph.addPlot(pie)
    self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

But I am getting a white color pie chart.
here is the image of my output.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9YZfopxzOv5UG9hQmRjZGVQdzQ
I updated my data source and delegate method.
Yes without overly I am getting this output -
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9YZfopxzOv5Uy14NXlQYkJZY1k

```
func numberOfRecordsForPlot(plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
    return UInt(pieItem)
}

func numberForPlot(plot: CPTPlot, field fieldEnum: UInt, recordIndex idx: UInt) -> AnyObject? {
    return pieChartValueArrayToShow[Int(idx)]
}

func pieChart(plot: CPTPieChart, sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex idx: UInt) {
    print("dataLabel was selected At Record Index getting called")
    self.pieChartDataLabel.text = "Your selected value is \(pieChartValueArrayToShow[Int(idx)])"
}
```

This is my Prepareforsegue Method where I am assigning the *pieChartValueArrayToShow* and *pieItem*

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowPieChart") {
        let desinationviewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PieChartViewController

        let count = pieChartValueArray.count as Int
        print(count)
        desinationviewController.pieItem = count//(sender?.integerValue)!//pieChartValueArray.count//
        print("count is \(pieChartValueArray.count)")
        desinationviewController.pieChartValueArrayToShow = pieChartValueArray
    }
    print("Prepare segue getting called\(sender)")
}
```

Comment: I tried this overlay setup in a Core Plot example app and it looked ok. Does the pie chart appear correctly without the overly? What datasource and delegate methods are implemented and what do they return? How many slices are in the pie? Does it have a border line around the slices? If so, what line style is used to draw the border line?

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch I updated the data source and delegate methods. Can you help me by giving some code sample. Thanks

Comment: Does the pie chart appear correctly without the overly? What is the value of `pieItem` (the slice count)?

Comment: Yes, PieItem  is the slice count and without overly the pie chart appears correctly. Here is the Image  ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9YZfopxzOv5Uy14NXlQYkJZY1k)

Comment: Is this a screenshot and not a PDF? Partially transparent elements don't render properly in PDFs.

Comment: Does the overlay draw when you remove the `backgroundColor` from the graph? If so, try setting the `fill` instead of the Core Animation `backgroundColor`. `graph.fill = CPTFill(color: .brownColor())`

Comment: Yes this was a screen shot. And when i am removing the background color i am getting this output https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9YZfopxzOv5T3JtTW9Ya1d2cVU

Comment: graph.fill = CPTFill(color: .brownColor())  has no effect

Comment: Are there any other views on screen at the same time as the graph? The `fill` is a pretty basic feature that should always work. What version of Core Plot and iOS are you using? Does the problem occur both on the simulator and device, or just the simulator?

Comment: No there is no other view in the graph. The  `fill`  has no effects means it also giving the same output what I was getting before by using  `graph.backgroundcolor`. I am using Core Plot 2.1 and iOS 9. I am getting this problem on the simulator. I did not check with the device.

Comment: What happens if you use a solid or semi-transparent color for the overlay instead of a gradient?

Comment: yes I gave some color to overly like this, `pie.overlayFill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.lightGrayColor())` . I am getting the PieChart with LightGray color

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with your code but it's clear the problem has something to do with the gradient. I tried that gradient in one of the Objective-C example apps and it worked fine, so the issue is probably in the translation to Swift. Keep experimenting. For example, does using a solid color fill with `CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)` work?

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking same. But not getting a proper solution. And also I don't need it now because my project requirement changed . Can  you please send me the code of gradient which you wrote for obj-c example?. And I applied `CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)` , but getting the PieChart with transparency color.

Comment: Thank you @EricSkroch for your support,  Finally I fixed it. There is a small flaw while setting overlay gradient. Instead of this -`overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0), atPosition: 0.9)`
I wrote `overlayGradient = overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0), atPosition: 0.8)
        overlayGradient = overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4), atPosition: 1.0)`    overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4), atPosition: 1.0)` . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by myself. I did a stupid mistake.
Instead of this

```
overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0), atPosition: 0.9)
overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4), atPosition: 1.0)
```

I Wrote

```
overlayGradient = overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0), atPosition: 0.8)
    overlayGradient = overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4), atPosition: 1.0)
```